# Best Pattern to Indifferently Compare Strings/Symbols for Equality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there an idiomatic Ruby pattern to test two 'strings' for equality that is indifferent to whether the operands are strings or symbols?

I'd like to use some operator to perform this comparison: `:abc == 'abc'.to_sym` without the need to normalize the operands to strings or symbols.

The `HashWithIndifferentAccess` behaviour in `active_support` is a pretty useful analogy for the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: FYI: You can look at the source which underlies HashWithIndifferentAccess [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to monkey patch the generic functionality in everywhere.

```
class Object
  def to_s_equals? var
    self.to_s == var
  end
end
```

As mentioned, only convert symbols to strings, not strings to symbols unless you have a subsequent use for the symbol. You could be more specific and only do that on Symbol

Alternatively you could add something for String and Symbols, but I can't think of a good common name.

```
class Symbol
  def equals_string? var
    self.to_s == var
  end
end 

class String
  def equals_symbol? var
    self == var.to_s
  end
end
```

Even then `equals` isn't quite right, but `match` infers a regex. `homologous` maybe? (corresponding in structure, but not necessarily function)

I don't think your getting much brevity on `to_s ==`. Maybe a bit of clarity enforcing the order you do the comparisons in.

Comment: This is a good solution, but I was ultimately seeking a way to do it without needing to resort to monkey-patching. It would seem that such a method does not really exist. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ruby 2.4 You can use `match?` method

```
> :abc.match?(/abc/)
=> true
> 'abc'.match?(/abc/)
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *regex* pattern to do this comparisons :-

```
/\Aabc\z/ === "abc" # => true
/\Aabc\z/ === :abc # => true
```

So, you can make your own method :-

```
def comparisons(sym, str, patt)
   [sym, str].all? { |i| patt === i }
end
comparisons(:abc, "abc", /\Aabc\z/) # => true
comparisons(:abc, "abcd", /\Aabc\z/) # => false
comparisons(:abcd, "abc", /\Aabc\z/) # => false
```

Comment: It would be easier on the caller to build the regex from `str`. `Regexp.new(/^#{str)$/)`

Comment: That should be `Regexp.new(/^#{Regexp.escape(str)}$/)` as you can have special characters.

Comment: @mtm Yes.. The *regex* in My answer is just a *hint* to the OP to say *yes there is a way*. :-)

Answer (score 0):

HashWithIndifferentAccess explicitly tests `is_a?(Symbol)` and, if so, converts it to a string.

Side note, converting a symbol to a string is probably better practice than the other direction.  Strings are subject to cleanup and symbols are not, so symbols will hang around forever and slowly leak memory.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that's how HashWithIndifferentAccess works; I'm just wondering if there's an operator that avoids littering my code with to_s or to_sym. Your point about memory leaks is a good one - I hadn't thought of that. It definitely makes sense to always convert in the string direction then.

Comment: You could patch some sort of `.EqlWithIndifferentAccess?` into string and symbol....but I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could also patch into `Symbol` if you know that the symbol will always be used as the receiver. Such as

```
 class Symbol
    alias_method :old_match, :=~
    def =~(s)
      old_match(s.is_a?(String) ? /#{Regexp.quote(s)}/ : s)
    end
 end

 :abc =~ "abc"
 #=> 0
 :abc =~ /abc/
 #=> 0
 :abc =~ "abcd"
 #=> nil
```

This will work the exact same way as `:abc =~` currently works but with a transformation of a `String` to a `Regex` first.

Although I generally suggest against monkey patching built in classes unless the implementation is isolated this should not have too many foreseeable side effects